# s25fs256s serial flash not responding with RTD2660

Tags: spi, embedded, 8051, vga

Hello guys,,
             I am interfacing RTD2660 with s25fs256s serial flash using SPI. but when i send the **command_type(0x46 (comman instruction type is read)) and command_data(0x9f (command for Device ID))** to RTD2660 to communicate with serial flash and read the Jedec ID but always it returns only 0xFFFFFF
at 0x67(high byte),0x68(middle byte),0x69(low byte) - >
*0xff,0xff,0xff*
 .
please help me out.

Comment: Connect a logic analyzer or oscilloscope to the clock, data-in, data-out, and chip select lines to observe what is happening during the communications.

Comment: KKrambo , Thanx for commenting ,i solved my problem there is some bad connectionn between RTD2660 and Serial flash.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by an asker who seems to have already found their solution in some trivial wiring error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello EveryOne,
              After a long Research ,my VGA card working with External Serial Flash s25fs256s.Some other wendors using W25x10/20/40 Winbond Serial flash(it's **less secure** in comparison with s25fs cypress Serial Flash).
i found some hardware connection problem now it's working fine.